# Triangulation of Rectified Image Points in Multiple Views

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am working with a set of calibrated images that form a ring around a foreground object ([1](http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/)).  I used Fusiello's method ([1](http://vision.middlebury.edu/mview/)) to rectify adjacent pairs of images, and then I performed disparity estimation.

When I take the matched points from a stereo pair and triangulate them, it forms an accurate point cloud.  Unfortunately, when I triangulate the points from another stereo image pair, this point cloud never aligns correctly with the original cloud.

Should calibrated, rectified images' point clouds merge together automatically?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the accuracy of calibration - both *intrinsic* (i.e. the same camera model - and how it handles distortion) and *extrinsic* (i.e. the camera pose in real space). Together, of course, these dictate the ultimate accuracy of your re-projection.

Do you have a measure of error for camera calibration - in terms of MSE re-projection?

Cumulative error is often noticeable in my experience if simply iterating over subsequent images. Some form of global optimisation often needs to be performed to first correct positions for all the camera poses.

The accuracy of your disparity estimation is also a factor. Not only in terms of the algorithm you using, but also in relation to the stereo baseline and how it relates to the size/nature of the object in question (how concave/convex), and how many sampling of the images you are taking (and the quality of those images - exposure/depth-of-field/etc).

Fundamentally, just how "off" are your point clouds? Are they close to being aligned (you could do a bit of ICP before triangulation...). Are they closer in the "centre" of the re-projection? Are they worse for projections taken from opposing images on opposite sides of the object?

Remember as well that (due to the discrete sampling) you shouldn't expect points to ever be re-projected exactly "on-top" on one another. Some form of binning operation during the triangulation pipeline usually occurs for handling this (hence most of the research work in visual hull -> voxels -> marching cubes -> triangulated surface around this...)

Have you checked out [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) BTW?

Comment: Shoot, I responded to your answer with an answer.  It's above. ;)